# In Safari for iPad, how can I get the current video position via Javascript?

Tags: ios, ipad, video, html5-video

When an embedded video is playing in an iPad browser, how can I retrieve the current `hh:mm:ss` position (and perhaps player state) in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in a webpage, you can do

```
var vid = document.getElementById('videoid');
var time = vid.currentTime;
```

as seen in http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#htmlmediaelement