# How to get position change events in Javascript for <video> in Mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, mobile-safari, html5-video

I want to execute a JavaScript function every second, or whenever the time position changes on a Mobile Safari video player during playback.

Is there an event listener or some way of achieving this? I see how to do it on-demand here:

[In Safari for iPad, how can I get the current video position via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442552/in-safari-for-ipad-how-can-i-get-the-current-video-position-via-javascript)

However, I'm looking for a way to fire the function automatically instead of requiring user interaction to trigger getting the position. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a ton of events you can hook into with HTML5 video. Not all will be supported by every browser, but Mobile Safari should do a pretty good job with what you need for this, which is the "timeupdate" event.

```
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  console.log('video time: ' + video.currentTime);
});
```

You can see a demonstrator for the events here:
http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: That page is a ton of info. Thank you!!